# ActiveRecord Ruby on Rails Select vs FInd_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to use ActiveRecord interface for a project. I have a function in Ruby, call it "get_val." Currently, I have

```
Object.find_by_sql("SELECT SUM(miles * gas * tires * get_val) AS calculation FROM table")
```

I would like to get this into ActiveRecord format, but I don't think I am allowed to use aggregate functions in 'select' function, and I'm not sure how to use 'calculate' function properly.

Additionally, I would like to add multiple where clauses, so my follow-up question is: Can I string together ActiveRecord functions in Rails and have it execute as a single SQL query? Particularly, can I string together 'find_by_sql' with 'where' if I wanted to?

NOTE: I am developing an old application, so I am using Rails 3, just in case ActiveRecord syntax has changed drastically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain off of select (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select):

```
Object.select("SUM(miles * gas * tires * get_val) AS calculation")
```

But not find_by_sql.

Comment: That works, thank you. Note that to get it to work, I had to use Ruby string interpolation: #{get_val}.